# Automatically load a VSPackage visual studio extension when a solution loads?

Tags: visual-studio, vspackage

I have created a visual studio extension and bound behaviour to build events. I want it to load automatically when the user loads a solution. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the attribute ProvideAutoLoadAttribute on your class that inherits from Package and pass it the guid that represents UI context where a solution is loaded:

```
[PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true)]
// This attribute is used to register the information needed to show this package
// in the Help/About dialog of Visual Studio.
[InstalledProductRegistration("#110", "#112", "1.0", IconResourceID = 400)]
[Guid(GuidList.guidHookIntoBuildEventsPkgString)]
[ProvideAutoLoadAttribute("{F1536EF8-92EC-443C-9ED7-FDADF150DA82}")]
public sealed class HookIntoBuildEventsPackage : Package
{
   ...
}
```

More UI contexts can be found here:
http://sandrinodimattia.net/blog/posts/some-clarity-on-auto-loading-visual-studio-2010-extensions/

Comment: You can also use UIContextGuids if you don't want to hardcode the GUIDs. For instance, autoload if a Solution exists by using:

[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids.SolutionExists)]

Comment: Do you know how to autoload a package if a solution with particular name is opened?